The way this login page functions is ok. But the signup form does not display when 'forgot password' is clicked
The signup form is meant to take password reset requests to the admin page. It does that perfectly. However due to the changes made, the signup form does not display when 'forgot password' has been clicked.
    <?php
        // Initialize a message variable for feedback
        $message = '';

        // Check if the form was submitted
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
                $employeeId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['employee_id']);
                $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

                // Define admin credentials
                $adminId = 'admin';
                $adminPassword = 'admin';

                // Check if the provided credentials match the admin credentials
                if ($employeeId === $adminId && $password === $adminPassword) {
                    // Redirect to the admin page
                    header("Location: admin.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $message = "Invalid Employee ID or Password.";
                }
            }

            if (isset($_POST['forgot_password'])) {
                $forgotEmployeeId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['forgot_employee_id']);
                // Log the password recovery request
                $logFile = 'password_recovery_requests.txt';
                $logEntry = "Password recovery requested for Employee ID: $forgotEmployeeId\n";
                file_put_contents($logFile, $logEntry, FILE_APPEND);

                $message = "Password recovery requested. Please contact the admin.";
            }
        }
        ?>



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const forgotPasswordLink = document.getElementById('forgot-password');
  const backToSigninLink = document.getElementById('back-to-signin');
  const signInForm = document.getElementById('signinform');
  const forgotPasswordForm = document.getElementById('forgot-password-form');
  const body = document.body;

  forgotPasswordLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    body.classList.add('signup');
  });

  backToSigninLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    body.classList.remove('signup');
  });
});
/* Reset CSS */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

body.signup {
  background: url(bg2.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

body:not(.signup) {
  background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 340px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .bg1,
.container .bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.container .bg1 {
  background: url(bg1.png);
}

.container .bg2 {
  background: url(bg2.png);
  opacity: 0;
}

body.signup .container .bg2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

body:not(.signup) .container .bg1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.signup .container .bg1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

form#forgot-password-form {
  left: 100%;
}

body.signup form#signinform {
  left: -100%;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form {
  left: 0;
}

form h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

form .inputBox {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

body:not(.signup) .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #000000;
}

body:not(.signup) .inputBox input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

body.signup .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

body.signup .inputBox input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

form .inputBox input[type="submit"] {
  background: #000435;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form .inputBox input[type="submit"] {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000435;
}

form .inputBox a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

body.signup form .inputBox a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

form .inputBox a:nth-child(2) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

form .inputBox b {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000435;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="bg1"></span>
    <span class="bg2"></span>
    <div id="error-container" class="error" style="<?php echo $message ? 'display: block;' : 'display: none;'; ?>">
      <?php echo $message; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form id="signinform" method="post">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox group">
        <a href="#" id="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In">
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Forgot Password Form -->
    <form id="forgot-password-form" method="post" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Forgot Password</h2>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="forgot_employee_id" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox group">
        <a href="#" id="back-to-signin">Already Have an Account?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" name="forgot_password" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>



I expected the signup form to display but instead it goes blank. I am not able to enter in the employee ID and send the password reset request. Kindly help on this issue.

You have forget to add the logic to show the Forget Password Form. You need to add forgotPasswordForm.style.display = "flex"; to forgotPasswordLink eventlistener and forgotPasswordForm.style.display = "none"; to backToSigninLinkeventlistener.
Thats all. Worth mentioning that I have not found button for backToSigninLink.
Below is working example. If this resolves your issue then accept it as answer so that it will help people with similar issue.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const forgotPasswordLink = document.getElementById('forgot-password');
  const backToSigninLink = document.getElementById('back-to-signin');
  const signInForm = document.getElementById('signinform');
  const forgotPasswordForm = document.getElementById('forgot-password-form');
  const body = document.body;
 

  forgotPasswordLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    body.classList.add('signup');
    forgotPasswordForm.style.display = "flex";
  });

  backToSigninLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    body.classList.remove('signup');
    forgotPasswordForm.style.display = "none";
  });
});
/* Reset CSS */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

body.signup {
  background: url(bg2.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

body:not(.signup) {
  background: url(bg1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 340px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .bg1,
.container .bg2 {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.container .bg1 {
  background: url(bg1.png);
}

.container .bg2 {
  background: url(bg2.png);
  opacity: 0;
}

body.signup .container .bg2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

body:not(.signup) .container .bg1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.signup .container .bg1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

form#forgot-password-form {
  left: 100%;
}

body.signup form#signinform {
  left: -100%;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form {
  left: 0;
}

form h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

form .inputBox {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

body:not(.signup) .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #000000;
}

body:not(.signup) .inputBox input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

body.signup .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

body.signup .inputBox input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

form .inputBox input[type="submit"] {
  background: #000435;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

body.signup form#forgot-password-form .inputBox input[type="submit"] {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000435;
}

form .inputBox a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

body.signup form .inputBox a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

form .inputBox a:nth-child(2) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

form .inputBox b {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000435;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="bg1"></span>
    <span class="bg2"></span>
    <div id="error-container" class="error" style="<?php echo $message ? 'display: block;' : 'display: none;'; ?>">
      <?php echo $message; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form id="signinform" method="post">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox group">
        <a href="#" id="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In">
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Forgot Password Form -->
    <form id="forgot-password-form" method="post" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Forgot Password</h2>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" name="forgot_employee_id" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" required>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox group">
        <a href="#" id="back-to-signin">Already Have an Account?</a>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="submit" name="forgot_password" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>



